# How to rank players highest score

Tags: sql

I have two tables

```
Players
id     Player
1      Jack
2      Anna
3      Sam

Scores
id     player_id     score
1      1             500
2      1             200
3      2             300
4      2             200
5      3             750
```

I would like the output to look like

```
1   Sam     750
2   Jack    500
3   Anna    300
```

Currently my code looks like

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY S.score DESC, P.name), P.name, S.score
FROM Players P, Scores S
WHERE P.id = S.player_id;
```

but my output is

```
1   Sam    750
2   Jack   500
3   Anna   300
4   Anna   200
5   Jack   200
```

I'm not sure how to get distinct player names, my attempts at using DISTINCT have not been working out. I'm just learning so apologies if this is something really obvious, i've tried to look for answers without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x.score DESC, x.name), x.name, x.score
FROM (
   SELECT P.Name, Max(S.Score) as score 
   FROM Players P, Scores S 
   WHERE P.id = S.player_id
   GROUP BY P.Name ) x 
ORDER BY x.score DESC, x.Name
```

First get the highest score per user, than rank the stuff.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has resolved my problem. There seems to be a small typo in your code on the last row "ORDER BY x.score DESC, P.Name" should have the P.Name be x.Name correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `rank()`instead of `row_number()` to handle ties.

Then, you should learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `join` syntax.

One method uses a subquery:

```
SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY s.max_score DESC), p.name, s.max_score
FROM (SELECT s.player_id, MAX(s.score) as max_score
      FROM Scores s
      GROUP BY s.player_id
     ) s JOIN
     Players P
     ON P.id = S.player_id
ORDER BY s.max_score DESC, P.Name;
```

You are using window functions, so you can do this without `GROUP BY` as:

```
SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY s.max_score DESC), p.name, s.max_score
FROM (SELECT s.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.player_id ORDER BY s.score DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Scores s
      GROUP BY s.player_id
     ) s JOIN
     Players P
     ON P.id = S.player_id
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY s.max_score DESC, P.Name;
```

Comment: The difference here seems to be that ties are ranked the same? two scores of 200 will both have same Rank? This might be something for me to keep in mind in the future. Thank you so much for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

My first inclination would be to use a subquery like the other suggested answers, but the following also seems to work, at least in SQL Server:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MAX(S.score) DESC), P.name, MAX(S.score)
FROM Players P INNER JOIN Scores S ON P.id = S.player_id
GROUP BY P.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find highest score by each player and sort it by marks.

1. Find the highest score by each player from scores table
2. Get the player name from Player table and Sort it by Highest score
3. Use Rank

   `SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY s.Score desc) as Rank, P.Player,S.score
       from (SELECT player_id, Max(Score) as score
          FROM Scores
          GROUP BY player_id) S
          INNER JOIN PLAYERS P
          ON P.id = S.player_id
          ORDER BY score desc`

   .